# Creating an Avro schema for a simple json

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, avro

I'm trying to build an avro schema for the following json:

```
{
  "id":1234,
  "my_name_field": "my_name",
  "extra_data": {
      "my_long_value": 1234567890,
      "my_message_string": "Hello World!",
      "my_int_value":  777,
      "some_new_field": 1
  }
}
```

The value for 'id' and 'my_name_field' are known but the fields in 'extra_data' dynamically change and are unknown.

The avro schema I had in mind is:

```
{
    "name":"my_record",
    "type":"record",
    "fields":[
        {"name":"id", "type":"int", "default":0},
        {"name":"my_name_field", "type":"string", "default":"NoName"},
        { "name":"extra_data", "type":{"type":"map", "values":["null","int","long","string"]}     }        
    ]
}
```

My first idea was to make 'extra_data' a record with a map, but this does not work:

```
{ "name":"extra_data", "type":{"type":"map", "values":["null","int","long","string"]} }
```

I get:

```
AvroTypeException: Expected start-union. Got VALUE_NUMBER_INT
```

apache gives some nice examples in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe but none seem to do the job.

This is the unit test I run to check:

public class AvroTest {

```
@Test
public void readRecord() throws IOException {

    String event="{\"id\":1234,\"my_name_field\":\"my_name\",\"extra_data\":{\"my_long_value\":1234567890,\"my_message_string\":\"Hello World!\",\"my_int_value\":777,\"some_new_field\":1}}";

    SchemaRegistry<Schema> registry = new com.linkedin.camus.schema.MySchemaRegistry();
    DecoderFactory decoderFactory = DecoderFactory.get();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    GenericDatumReader<GenericData.Record> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericData.Record>();
    Schema schema = registry.getLatestSchemaByTopic("record_topic").getSchema();
    reader.setSchema(schema);

    HashMap hashMap = mapper.readValue(event, HashMap.class);
    long now = Long.valueOf(hashMap.get("now").toString())*1000;
    GenericData.Record read = reader.read(null, decoderFactory.jsonDecoder(schema, event));
}
```

Would appreciate help with this,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the list of extra data fields is really unknown using multiple optional value fields may help, like this:

```
{
    "name":"my_record",
    "type":"record",
    "fields":[
        {"name":"id", "type":"int", "default":0},
        {"name":"my_name_field", "type":"string", "default":"NoName"},
        {"name":"extra_data", "type": "array", "items": {
            {"name": "extra_data_entry", "type":"record", "fields": [
                {"name":"extra_data_field_name", "type": "string"},
                {"name":"extra_data_field_type", "type": "string"},
                {"name":"extra_data_field_value_string", "type": ["null", "string"]},
                {"name":"extra_data_field_value_int", "type": ["null", "int"]},
                {"name":"extra_data_field_value_long", "type": ["null", "long"]}
            ]}
        }}
    ]
}
```

Then you can select the `extra_data_field_value_*` value based on the `extra_data_field_type` for that field.